# NodeJS variable not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I can't seem to find a problem why this is not working. When I go to localhost:3000 I get this error `ReferenceError: pixwords is not defined`

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
Word.find().then((pixwords) => {
    if(!pixwords) {
     return res.send('No text available');
    }
});
res.render('index.hbs', {pixwords});
});
```

This is index.hbs:

```
{{#each pixwords}}
    {{this.text}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Could you paste your full code?

Comment: `pixwords` is only defined inside the `Word.find().then()` context, not outside.

Comment: @ThomasLombart It's a result from a `Word` model, so it contains all the words from collection.

Comment: `pixwords` does not exist outside the callback

Comment: You are calling res.render immediately after calling Word.find.  You need to call render in the callback of then()

Comment: The answers to the linked questions address the real issue here (trying to use the result of an asynchronous call before the call completes), but note that separately, there's a quite basic scope issue. Obviously, you can't use a variable or parameter outside the function in which it's declared.

Answer (score 2):

`pixwords` is only defined in the callback function of `Word.find().then()`, you can only use it there:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Word.find().then((pixwords) => { // <-- this declares pixwords
    if (!pixwords) {
      return res.send('No text available');
    }
    res.render('index.hbs', { // <-- move the call in the .then
      pixwords
    });
  });
  // anything here is executed before Word.find has finished running
});
```

Comment: This is one of the most often-repeated duplicates on SO. We really don't need *another* answer to it.